# jQuery find children and assign value by order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<div class="A1">
    <div class="child">A1-1</div>
    <div class="child">A1-2</div>
    <div class="child">A1-3</div>
    <div class="child">A1-4</div>
    <div class="A2">
        <div class="child">A2-1</div>
        <div class="child">A2-2</div>

        <div class="A3">
            <div class="child">A3-1</div>
            <div class="child">A3-2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to know how to assign a value to each child of `class .A1` for example based on order. so if A1-1 is the first like on the code it will be assigned : 1 
if I reorder it :

```
<div class="child">A1-3</div>
<div class="child">A1-2</div>
<div class="child">A1-1</div>
<div class="child">A1-4</div>
```

then now A1-1 will have a value of 3.
any  thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "value"? div elements don't have a value attribute. Do you just want to include children of "A1" that have the class "child", or should "A2" be included too? (How about the children of "A2"?)

Comment: a number ... I am trying to save the values to a database that way I can display the results by priority. descending

Comment: this is confusing, if you change A1 - 1 to A1 - 3, what difference is there from the initial structure? Or are you talking of the element index - which is now the third element in the div?

Comment: I mean, how/where do you want to store the number value? div elements are not form elements so they don't have a value property and won't be submitted. Do you want to go ahead and assign a `data-value="3"` attribute, or put the values in an array so you can submit them via Ajax to store in your database, or...?

Comment: I want to change them I just want to get their order. order of which they are displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.A1').children().each(function (index,element) {
    $(element).html('A1-' + (index + 1));
});
```

Comment: it changed the first element to A1-0, the other elements disappeared

Comment: Are other elements children of your first element by any chance?

Comment: that was my mistake there was another class under that one. thank you worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/justiceerolin/wH4UG/

So that it'll work for all instance of A-N.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, div elements don't have a `value` attribute, so the following creates a `data-value` attribute that will be set to 1 for the first child, 2 for the second and so forth:

```
$(".A1").children().each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("data-value", index + 1);
});
```

That attribute will stay with each element even if you move them around within the DOM.

If you want to submit the values to your database then presumably you want to associate the index "1" with the contents of its div "A1-1" (or "A1-3" in your last example). If so you can do something like this:

```
var values = {};
$(".A1").children().each(function(index) {
    values[index + 1] = $(this).html();
});
$.post("yourURLtoSubmitDataTo", values);
```

Where the `values` object will end up something like:

```
{
   "1" : "A1-3",
   "2" : "A1-2",
   "3" : "A1-1",
   "4" : "A1-4"
}
```